# Age Range to Age Numerical value(python)

Tags: python

I want to transform age range to age numerical value. I used def Age(x) & If statement to transform, but it doesn't work and give the wrong result.
I attached the images of the step that I did and the result.
The dataset that I used is BlackFriday.
Please help me to clarify the mistakes.
Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please paste your relevant code and data in plain text in the question instead of using captures. Links can break and images are not very handy.

Comment: How could this be upvoted? Code is only in images, and if the data was clean and correct, the transformation function should have worked. Please give a **reproducible** [mcve]. The rules given in [ask] help others to identify your actual problem and post relevant solutions instead of guessing and trying to fix a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Given what is shown from the result of `value_counts`, it seems like a simple [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for ages of `55+` will do:

```
df.Age.str.extract(r'(?<=-)(\d+)').fillna(56)
```

---

Lets consider the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':['26-35','36-45', '55+']})

    Age
0  26-35
1  36-45
2    55+

df.Age.str.extract(r'(?<=-)(\d+)').fillna(56).rename(columns={0:'Age'})

   Age
0  35
1  45
2  56
```

Comment: This is correct, but with **your** dataframe, `df.Age.transform(Age)` gives the same result...

Comment: `transform(Age)`?? Correct me if I'm wrong, but `transform` takes an aggregation function. Not sure I understand what you're trying to do @SergeBallesta

Comment: [Series.transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html) uses a simple 1-1 transformation function. And `df.Age` is a `Series`. Just try this: `def Age(a):
 mapping = {'0-17': 17, '26-35': 35, '36-45': 45, '46-50': 50}
 return mapping.get(a, 56)` and `df.Age.transform(Age)`

Comment: Ah you mean mapping by a custom function... Sure why not that's another approach

Comment: I used that one because it involved less typing, but it is close to the function OP has shown.

Answer (score 0):

A simple function to modifiy age_range to mean:

Here is the age ranges we have

```
temp_df['age_range'].unique()

array([70, '18-25', '26-35', '36-45', '46-55', '56-70'], dtype=object)
```

Function to modify age

```
def mod_age(df):
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if(df.loc[i,'age_range']==70):
        df.loc[i,'age_range']=70
    elif(df.loc[i,'age_range']=='18-25'):
        df.loc[i,'age_range']=(18+25)//2
    elif(df.loc[i,'age_range']=='26-35'):
        df.loc[i,'age_range']=(26+35)//2
    elif(df.loc[i,'age_range']=='36-45'):
        df.loc[i,'age_range']=(36+45)//2
    elif(df.loc[i,'age_range']=='46-55'):
        df.loc[i,'age_range']=(46+55)//2
    elif(df.loc[i,'age_range']=='56-70'):
        df.loc[i,'age_range']=(56+75)//2

 age_range  family_size marital_status  sum
2   70         2        Single          4
25  40         4        Single          2
5   21         2        Married         4
32  50         3        Single          3
13  30         2        Single          5
```